Wikibase Search action giving Host not allowed error
Im trying to search entities by text in a local wikibase instance using the following SPARQL query
SELECT * WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search" .
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "wikibase.svc" .
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:srsearch "oviedo" .
        ?itemId wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
        }
}
LIMIT 20

When the query is executed I get the following error: Host wikibase.svc is not allowed
Therefore I dont understand what is supposed to be the wikibase:endpoint.
I have checked the names of my containers and it seem all correct, they are in the same network too. My docker-compose.yml is the following:
# Example Wikibase docker compose setup
version: "3.4"

x-common-variables: &wikibase_variables
  DB_SERVER: mysql.svc:3306
  MW_ADMIN_NAME: ${MW_ADMIN_NAME}
  MW_ADMIN_PASS: ${MW_ADMIN_PASS}
  MW_ADMIN_EMAIL: ${MW_ADMIN_EMAIL}
  MW_WG_SECRET_KEY: ${MW_SECRET_KEY}
  # Disable jobs running after requests when wikibase-jobrunner is defined
  MW_WG_JOB_RUN_RATE: 0
  DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
  DB_PASS: ${DB_PASS}
  DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
  WIKIBASE_HOST: ${WIKIBASE_HOST}

services:
  wikibase:
    image: "${WIKIBASE_BUNDLE_IMAGE_NAME}"
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${WIKIBASE_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      # # This shares the configuration with jobrunner
      - shared:/var/www/html/:rw
      # # Uncomment this next line to mount your own LocalSettings.php file
      # # also uncomment the same line in the wikibase-jobrunner service!
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.d/LocalSettings.override.php
      - ./Wikibase.default.php:/var/www/html/extensions/Wikibase/repo/config/Wikibase.default.php
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${WIKIBASE_HOST}
          - wikibase-docker.svc
    environment:
      <<: *wikibase_variables
      WIKIBASE_PINGBACK:
      MW_WG_ENABLE_UPLOADS:

  wikibase-jobrunner:
    image: "${WIKIBASE_BUNDLE_IMAGE_NAME}"
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: /jobrunner-entrypoint.sh
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - shared:/shared/:ro
      - ./jobrunner-entrypoint.sh:/jobrunner-entrypoint.sh
      # # Uncomment this next line to mount your own LocalSettings.php file
      # # also uncomment the same line in the wikibase service
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.d/LocalSettings.override.php
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - wikibase-jobrunner.svc
    environment:
      <<: *wikibase_variables
      MAX_JOBS: ${MAX_JOBS}

  mysql:
    image: "${MYSQL_IMAGE_NAME}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mediawiki-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      # CONFIG - Change the default values below (should match values passed to wikibase)
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - mysql.svc
  
  wdqs-frontend:
    image: "${WDQS_FRONTEND_IMAGE_NAME}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${WDQS_FRONTEND_PORT}:80"
    depends_on:
      - wdqs-proxy
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${WDQS_FRONTEND_HOST}
    environment:
      - WIKIBASE_HOST
      - WDQS_HOST=wdqs-proxy.svc

  wdqs:
    image: "${WDQS_IMAGE_NAME}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: /runBlazegraph.sh
    # Set number of files ulimit high enough, otherwise blazegraph will abort with:
    # library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory
    # Appeared on Docker 24.0.5, containerd 1.7.9, Linux 6.6.6, NixOS 23.11
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 32768
        hard: 32768
    volumes:
      - query-service-data:/wdqs/data
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - wdqs.svc
    environment:
      - WIKIBASE_HOST
      - WDQS_HOST=wdqs.svc
      - WDQS_PORT=9999
    expose:
      - 9999

  wdqs-proxy:
    image: "${WDQS_PROXY_IMAGE_NAME}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PROXY_PASS_HOST=wdqs.svc:9999
    depends_on:
      - wdqs
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - wdqs-proxy.svc

  wdqs-updater:
    image: "${WDQS_IMAGE_NAME}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: /runUpdate.sh
    # Set number of files ulimit high enough, otherwise blazegraph will abort with:
    # library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory
    # Appeared on Docker 24.0.5, containerd 1.7.9, Linux 6.6.6, NixOS 23.11
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 32768
        hard: 32768
    depends_on:
      - wdqs
      - wikibase
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - wdqs-updater.svc
    environment:
      - WIKIBASE_HOST
      - WDQS_HOST=wdqs.svc
      - WDQS_PORT=9999
      # CONFIG - WIKIBASE_SCHEME can be set to 'https' if the updater should expect https concept uris

volumes:
  shared:
  mediawiki-mysql-data:
  query-service-data:


did you setup the allowed endpoints as described here? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI

Yes, its already in there but the file names are different. In the example file is mwapi.json but in my container is mwservices.json.
